# Redirect in .htaccess makes javascript not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a small redirect to let my `index.php` resolve all parameters, but in some cases it can't find my javascript files anymore.

This small .htaccess rewrites all requests that don't exist to `index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php/$1
```

A piece of my `index.php` where the javascript url returns `index.php` instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

- www.mysite.com/foo is working fine
- www.mysite.com is working as well
- www.mysite.com/foo/foo isn't working. It returns `index.php` as a
  javascript file when I inspect it with firebug.

Why is the relative path changed? I am redirecting to `index.php` so I'm expecting to be in that folder.

As an alternative: How can I get the full path of the javascript that is being requested for debugging purposes? Is there a way to find the .js requests that are being made by `index.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the extra slash, the browser thinks that your relative links (e.g. `"scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"`) have a URI base in a subdirectory. So you either need to make your links absolute instead of relative:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Or add a relative URI base in your header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

---

The other thing here is that your second rewrite rule doesn't have any conditions. `RewriteCond`s **only** get applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`. The other thing is that the first rule will always get applied because `(.*)` matches everything, including URI's with a trailing slash. Thus the second rule never gets applied. You should always make the slash optional:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php/$1
```

Comment: I can't quite understand why that is the case. If I'm redirecting to index.php I would expect that the scripts are requested as coming from the index.php folder.

Comment: @Marnix Your redirect is entirely on the server's end. The browser still thinks it's seeing the resource located at: `www.mysite.com/foo/foo`, which means the relative URI base is `/foo/`, and thus when it sees a relative URI, it appends the base that it thinks is correct to it.

Comment: But how would it be easy to move these folders around without changing the paths of each file every time you want to move something?

Comment: @Marnix You don't need to change where the scripts are, just tell the browser that `/foo/` *isn't* the base, and that `/` is. You do that by adding `/` in front of the links, or simply adding a `<base>` tag to your header.

Comment: This seems to go right for all my cases I've showed in my question. But this case doesn't seem to work: www.mysite.com/foo/foo/?boo=hey. My `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` becomes /index.php/foo/foo/foo. That doesn't make sense to me.